# Android JUnit testing ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse, junit

I'm trying to setup JUnit to test my activities for an android project.

The Android Project runs ok on both an AVD and a device (there are still a few bugs left, which is why I want to add a few unit tests)

I followed the steps from these websites (they are more or less the same, but I still checked all of them just to make sure I did everything correctly)
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-junit-testing/
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_eclipse.html

I created a test project using the same workspace as my project, and created my first test case. When I tried to run the test, I got the following:

> [2012-12-09 19:42:56 - AssassinTest] Android Launch!
>   [2012-12-09 19:42:56 - AssassinTest] adb is running normally.
>   [2012-12-09 19:42:56 - AssassinTest] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
>   [2012-12-09 19:42:56 - AssassinTest] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Google_Level10' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
>   [2012-12-09 19:42:56 - AssassinTest] Uploading AssassinTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   [2012-12-09 19:42:57 - AssassinTest] Installing AssassinTest.apk...
>   [2012-12-09 19:42:59 - AssassinTest] Success!
>   [2012-12-09 19:42:59 - AssassinTest] Project dependency found, installing: Assassin
>   [2012-12-09 19:43:01 - Assassin] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
>   [2012-12-09 19:43:01 - AssassinTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5554
>   [2012-12-09 19:43:01 - AssassinTest] Collecting test information
>   [2012-12-09 19:43:04 - AssassinTest] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'

And here is what I get from LogCat:

```
12-09 19:43:02.929: E/dalvikvm(1255): Unable to resolve Ludes/assassi/test/InGameActivityTest; annotation class 19
12-09 19:43:02.929: D/AndroidRuntime(1255): Shutting down VM
12-09 19:43:02.929: W/dalvikvm(1255): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.Test
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaredAnnotations(Method.java:262)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotations(AccessibleObject.java:188)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getAnnotation(AccessibleObject.java:196)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod.getAnnotation(TestMethod.java:60)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.HasMethodAnnotation.apply(HasMethodAnnotation.java:39)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.HasMethodAnnotation.apply(HasMethodAnnotation.java:30)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at com.android.internal.util.Predicates$OrPredicate.apply(Predicates.java:106)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.HasAnnotation.apply(HasAnnotation.java:42)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.HasAnnotation.apply(HasAnnotation.java:31)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at com.android.internal.util.Predicates$NotPredicate.apply(Predicates.java:122)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.satisfiesAllPredicates(TestSuiteBuilder.java:254)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.build(TestSuiteBuilder.java:184)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:373)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3246)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Test in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/data/app/udes.assassin.test-1.apk:/data/app/udes.assassin-2.apk]
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-09 19:43:02.961: E/AndroidRuntime(1255):     ... 25 more
```

While searching on a few forums, I read that this might be caused by a bad manifest file, but I don't see what is wrong with mine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="udes.assassin.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="udes.assassin" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

And finally, this is the code in my only JUnit class (so far)

```
package udes.assassin.test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import udes.assassin.InGameActivity;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class InGameActivityTest 
        extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<InGameActivity> {

    public InGameActivityTest() {
        super("udes.assassin", InGameActivity.class);
    }

    public InGameActivityTest(Class<InGameActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Before
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSetItemPosition() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is probably because JUnit is not in your classpath. Go to `Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` and check if the JUnit box is unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

I notice that, you are using @Test annotation:

```
@Test
public void testSetItemPosition() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

That's introduced by junit4, and android test based on junt3. see [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html)

You should remove @Test annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Same mistake here, other reason...

My test class was in an anonymous package but it was inconistent with AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="micharg.nameanimalthing" />
```